# Smack version 4.2.4 : resource-constraint - wait

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

Ejabberd version `17.11`

I integrated `4.2.4` smack library.

Now when user have more than 5 team and join => then it give error :at `org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:355)`
like

`org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPP error reply received from 153062971823588.0@conference.dev-chat.hlth.care/chpr4e33d9@dev-chat.hlth.care/8752201883455555585578942:' XMPPError: resource-constraint - wait`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have this option set to 5?
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#limiting-opened-sessions-with-acl